# How to read text from textfile and store every character in an array

Tags: c

I'm trying to read text from duom.txt file and store every char into array.
But i don't get the right answer.
What's wrong with my code ?

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
FILE *in;
char ch,str[100],cw;
int j,i = 0;

in=fopen("duom.txt","r");


if(in){
   while(!feof(in)){
   ch=getc(in);
   str[i] = ch;
   i++;
}
}

for(j=0;j<i;j++){
             printf("%c",str[i]);
}
printf("\n");
  fclose(in);


   system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

duom.txt file:

```
My name is Lukas
```

Comment: I know this isn't in answer to your question but your code formatting is disgusting. Try and practice proper indentation and syntax 'beautification' so you don't potentially confuse yourself in the future.

Answer (score 1):

1. fgetc() returns an `int` so type of `ch` should be  `int`.
2. feof() tells whether you have *read past* the end of file. That means your while loop will be executed one more time than desired.

Answer (score 1):

You should put `j` instead of `i` in the print loop:

```
for(j=0;j<i;j++){
         printf("%c",str[i]); // <-- here, it must be `str[j]`
}
```

That's why you should allways use meaningful variable names!

Answer (score 1):

There is a small typo in your program.

```
for(j=0;j<i;j++){
     printf("%c",str[j]); //str[j] instead of str[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake in the code is that

```
for(j=0;j<i;j++){
         printf("%c",str[i]); // <-- here, it must be `str[j]`
}
```

the change of variable results in a diaster in a program
so edit it and try